# Get control property by knowing typeName and contorl name

Tags: c#, controls

I have to access to some controls properties by knowing what type of control is and the name of control:

For example:

```
Type myType1 = Type.GetType("System.Windows.Forms.Button");

var ctrl_Prop = this.Controls.OfType<>().Where(r => r.Name == "myButton");
```

Question is how to pass here `this.Controls.OfType<>` type of control?

Comment: Take a look at [C# generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/): `this.Controls.OfType<Button>()...`

Comment: `this.Controls.OfType<Control>().Where(r => r.Name == "myButton");`. `Name` belongs to the common base class. It doesn't include components, of course (so you won't find a ToolTip).